# Execute the program every 5 minutes with gocron

Tags: go, go-modules, golang-migrate

I need to run my Co program continuously with five minute interval.

I tried using [gocron](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-co-op/gocron) but the program is not giving any output.

```
func hi() {
    fmt.Println("hi")
}
func main() {
    gocron.Every(5).Minute().Do(hi)
}
```

I expect this to run and print "hi" at every 5 min interval.

Comment: Didn't you forget to start the gocron scheduler ? See there: https://github.com/jasonlvhit/gocron

Answer (score 4):

Your code is only setup a rule and immediately exits. You have to start the scheduler which will run the assigned jobs.

```
scheduler := gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)
scheduler.Every(5).Minute().Do(hi)
scheduler.StartBlocking()
```

This way the scheduler will block the program until its stopped (by Ctrl-C for example).

See the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-co-op/gocron) for more info.